# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins - package does not exist

Tags: spring, maven, web-applications, maven-2, maven-plugin

I'm trying to use `mvn install`, but I keep getting this error

```
    Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project example-module-core: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/terasoluna-plus/example-module-core/src/main/java/com/mycompany/project/module/util/InitServlet.java:[10,47] package org.springframework.web.context.support does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/terasoluna-plus/example-module-core/src/main/java/com/mycompany/project/module/service/impl/DatabaseServiceImpl.java:[9,50] package org.springframework.transaction.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/terasoluna-plus/example-module-core/src/main/java/com/mycompany/project/module/service/impl/DatabaseServiceImpl.java:[22,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Transactional
[ERROR] /C:/terasoluna-plus/example-module-core/src/main/java/com/mycompany/project/module/service/impl/InitializerServiceImpl.java:[11,50] package org.springframework.transaction.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/terasoluna-plus/example-module-core/src/main/java/com/mycompany/project/module/service/impl/InitializerServiceImpl.java:[28,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Transactional
[ERROR] /C:/terasoluna-plus/example-module-core/src/main/java/com/mycompany/project/example-module-core/src/main/java/com/mycompany/project/module/util/InitServlet.java:[25,11] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable SpringBeanAutowiringSupport
[ERROR] location: class com.mycompany.SIAR.module.util.InitServlet
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

In my InitServlet.java I have all the imports, and it has no errors. In the pom.xml I have all dependencies needed, but this problem always persists.

All the other solutions tell me to add the dependency and use Maven Update, but it is definitely not missing code/dependencies, because this project is being shared with 2 other users, and it works fine on the other machines. It is the exact same project.

I had this working for a few hours, after countless tries of `mvn clean install`, one of them got the BUILD SUCCESS and I didn't change anything, and it was working fine. But later, after changing some java files, I used `mvn clean install`, and got again the same error.

Any ideias of what it might be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it. Apparently it really needed 2 more dependencies on a pom.xml that was on another folder. I needed to add to a pom.xml that was in a core folder, these 2 dependencies.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.terasoluna.plus.framework</groupId>
  <artifactId>terasoluna-plus-web-conf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

After adding it, I ran `mvn clean install`, and it installed successfully. Thank you anyway for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

At time when it is working on other systems with exact pom , and not working on mine, I look into differences....

1. In my local repository - Delete the problematic dependency and run mvn clean install. Whatever dependencies are needed will be downloaded again by maven.
2. In my maven settings.xml - at the location ${MAVEN_HOME}/conf.What is the difference , did I over-ride any settings?
3. Difference in JDK version or Maven version.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried your solution, but the same error persist. JDK version and Maven is exactly the same, because these are all new machines and they were all installed with the same files.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `maven-compiler-plugin` into `pom.xml`. you can find the plugin code below and replace the source version by your jdk version:

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <source>1.8</source>   // jdk version
            <target>1.8</target>   // jdk version
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```